# Integer ID pool

Tags: python, programming-challenge, unit-testing

I would really appreciate some feedback on the code I wrote to solve the following problem:

> #### Design an IdManager.
>
> IdManager manages a pool of integer ids. (from 1 to n). It should
>   provide api’s to `get_id()` and `free_id()`.
>
> `get_id()`: It returns any id , available in the pool. An Id cannot be
>   given away again, unless it has been freed.
>
> `free_id(int id)`: It returns the id back to the pool, so that it can be
>   given out again.
>
> Discuss the api’s definitions, data structures and write tests.

Here is my description:

I used two data structures in my ID Manager. My goal was to make both free_id and get_id \$O(1)\$. I used a dictionary
to keep track of which ids are free, and a list as a stack to give the free ids away. The problem I addressed with 
the dictionary was that if I just used a stack to manage the ids, the user of the API could call free_id multiple 
times on an id that was already free, and fill the stack up with ids that were not really free. So I decided to use a
dictionary to keep track of whether an id was free or not. That way I can only add an id to the stack if the id is 
marked False and raise an exception if a user tries to call free_id on an id that is already free. The result is that
free_id uses append on a list which is \$O(1)\$, set on a dictionary which is also \$O(1)\$ and in dictionary which is also 
\$O(1)\$. In get_id, I call pop on the stack which is \$O(1)\$, as well as set on the dictionary which is also \$O(1)\$.

```
import unittest


class IDManager():
    def __init__(self, n):
        """
        :param pool: integer to create pool from 1 to n
        :return: IDManager for managing pool of ids
        """
        if not isinstance(n, int):
            raise Exception('N must be an int, got type {}'.format(type(n)))
        self.id_dict = {i: True for i in range(1, n + 1)}
        self.stack = [i for i in range(1, n + 1)]

    def get_id(self):
        """
        :return: a freed integer id
        """
        if not self.stack:
            raise Exception('All ids are currently in use, use free_id to free ids')
        return_id = self.stack.pop()
        self.id_dict[return_id] = False
        return return_id

    def free_id(self, id):
        """
        :param id: integer id to be freed
        """
        if id not in self.id_dict:
            raise Exception('id {} is not a valid id'.format(id))
        if self.id_dict[id]:
            raise Exception('id {} is already free'.format(id))
        self.id_dict[id] = True
        self.stack.append(id)


class TestIDManager(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.manager = IDManager(100)

    def test_free_id(self):
        """
        test that IDManager.free_id(id) puts the id back on the stack and marks the id as free in id_dict
        """
        mid = self.manager.get_id()
        length = len(self.manager.stack)
        self.manager.free_id(mid)
        assert len(self.manager.stack) == length + 1
        assert self.manager.id_dict[mid]

    def test_get_id(self):
        """
        test that IDManager.get_id() returns an id that is an integer and marks the id as in use in id_dict
        and removes it from the stack
        """
        previous_length = len(self.manager.stack)
        mid = self.manager.get_id()
        self.assertIsInstance(mid, int)
        assert not self.manager.id_dict[mid]
        assert len(self.manager.stack) == previous_length - 1

    def test_wrong_value(self):
        """
        tests that an exception is thrown if IDManager() is created with a non integer value
        """
        self.assertRaises(Exception, lambda: IDManager('string'))

    def test_free_free_id(self):
        """
        tests that an exception is thrown if an id is freed that is already free
        """
        fid = self.manager.get_id()
        self.manager.free_id(fid)
        self.assertRaises(Exception, lambda: self.manager.free_id(fid))

    def test_no_ids(self):
        """
        tests to make sure an exception is thrown if get_id() is called with no free ids
        """
        for i in range(100):
            self.manager.get_id()
        self.assertRaises(Exception, lambda: self.manager.get_id())

    def test_bad_id(self):
        """
        tests to make sure an exception is thrown if get_id() is called with an invalid id
        """
        self.assertRaises(Exception, lambda: self.manager.free_id(10001))
```

Comment: Aside from code concerns, `IDManager` is a somewhat useless name. It basically says "i have some unspecified bureaucratic role regarding IDs". You might be better off designing an `IDPool` instead -- that at least hints at what it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about just using a set to store ids?  Then you don't need double storage.

Eg

```
class IdManagerException(Exception): pass

class IdManager(object):
  def __init__(self, n):
    self.max = n
    self.ids = set(range(1, n + 1))

  def get_id(self):
    try:
      return self.ids.pop()
    except KeyError:
      raise IdManagerException("no available ids")

  def free_id(self, n):
    if n > self.max:
      raise IdManagerException("id %d out of range (max %d)" % (n, self.max))

    self.ids.add(n) # no-op if n already there, do we care?
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, chacmool. I hope you enjoy the site.

Comment: Oh man I should have thought of that. Thanks!